# Facing issue while writing SQL in pyspark

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert below SQL code to pyspark. Can someone please help me

```
UPDATE B 
SET col = 'a'
FROM table B
WHERE (case when left(util,1) in ('A', 'B') then count  else PROCS end < 1)
```

Here, util, count, procs are column names.

while coding in pyspark, i can create a new column 'col' like this:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("col", case condition ,a)
```

Comment: I suspect that if you converted the above into simple `AND` and `OR` logic you would have an easier time. I would also suggest changing `left(util,1) in ('A', 'B')` to `util LIKE '[AB]%`. Doing that and getting rid of the `CASE` expression will mean you then have a SARGable query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when` for doing the equivalent of `update`:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn(
    'col', 
    F.when(
        F.expr("case when left(util,1) in ('A', 'B') then count else PROCS end < 1"),
        F.lit('a')
    ).otherwise(F.col('col'))
)
```